# Unable to convert text file to binary file

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I have the assignment to read a file (**datain.txt**), convert it into a binary file and finally read the binary file again to print out the information in that file.

I have made an attempt to debug my code for many times and I find that the error occur in the function `convertfile`. For details, the file pointer `datain` do not move around but just read the first line instead. I think that `fscanf` moves the pointer but it is false in this case.  Therefore, the data of dynamic memory `input` does not change at all.

--> Output:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0

The file input I use:

> 1 JoeyMathel 0385788060 joeymathel@gmail.com
>
> 2 ScottyJack 0325621458 scottyjack@gmail.com
>
> 3 JohnMarker 0230125214 johnmarker@gmail.com
>
> 4 KarlKarper 0213020352 karlkarper@gmail.com

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAXWORD 100

typedef struct address address;
struct address
{
    int stt;
    char name[100], telephone_number[20], email[100];
};

bool checktoread(FILE *in)
{
    return in == NULL;
}
void inputdata(FILE *datain, int max, address *array)
{
    while(fread(array, sizeof(address), max, datain)>0);
}
void convertfile(FILE *datain, FILE *dataout, int max)
{
    address *input = (address *)malloc(sizeof(address)*max);
    int size = sizeof(address);
    int i = 0;
    while (i<max)
    {
        fscanf(datain, "%d", &input[i].stt);
        fscanf(datain, "%s", input[i].name);
        fscanf(datain, "%s", input[i].telephone_number);
        fscanf(datain, "%s\n", input[i].email);
        i++;

    }
    fwrite(input, size, max, dataout);
    free(input);
}
void printout(address *directory, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < max; i++)
        printf("%-4d%-20s%-20s%-30s\n", directory[i].stt, directory[i].name, directory[i].telephone_number, directory[i].email);
}
int countline(FILE *in)
{
    int i = 0;
    char string[100];
    while(fgets(string, 100, in)!= NULL)
    i++;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    FILE *fpin = fopen("datain.txt", "r");
    FILE *fpout = fopen("phonebook.dat", "rb+");
    int max = countline(fpin);
    rewind(fpin);
    address *directory = (address *)malloc(sizeof(address)*max);
    if (checktoread(fpin))
    {
        printf("This file is empty or unable to be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    convertfile(fpin, fpout, max);
    rewind(fpin);
    rewind(fpout);
    fclose(fpin);
    inputdata(fpout, max, directory);
    printout(directory, max);
    fclose(fpout);
    free(directory);
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: “convert it into a binary file” — what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I means that I want to convert the original file (txt file) into a binary file (dat file)

Comment: That’s what you already wrote. But in isolation this doesn’t really make sense, as “binary file” isn’t something specific or well-defined.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know whether you know the definition of binary files or not. If you don't you should search it on Google. In this case, I need to change from the letter (character) file into a file in binary data. I don't know how to explain more if you still don;t understand

Comment: By the way, your other `fscanf`'s need to pass the address of as well.

Comment: @jiveturkey With an exception of ``stt`` no other ``fscanf`` need to be passed with the address. Or do you want me to pass the address of anything else?

Comment: Please be kind, we all like to help you. But you should be more specific what you mean by "binary file", as each file is binary in the end.

Comment: @Scotty Believe me, I know the definition. The term “binary data” is not as informative as you think it is. Technically text is *also* binary data — as is everything else your computer stores. Which is why I’m asking after details.

Comment: My apologies.  Not taking my time.

Comment: Your code works as expected on my machines (Ubuntu 19.04, GCC 8 as well as Windows 10, Visual Studio).

Comment: @MathiasSchmid Oh really? I am currently using VS code with the GCC is MinGW. I am also using the x64 bit version of windows. Is that a factor that causes the wrong output?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually you should read my source code first because I have posted already that my binary file is .dat file, not .txt.

Comment: @Scotty Both Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10 are 64-bit. I checked your code with MinGW (MinGW-32 7.3 and MinGW-64 8.1) which works on my machine as well. Sorry, no idea what might going wrong in your environment.

Comment: @Scotty I found just one thing in your code which might lead to similar wrong output you mentioned in your question.
You open the output file `phonebook.dat` with attributes `rb+` which expects that the file exists and might not be true at initial execution.
If that's the case than you could either add an empty output file or use attributes `wb+`.